# Sample modification or weighting for partially paired data?

Tags: weighted-sampling

I want to analyze age and gender related differences of serum levels of an antibiotic agent, which was administered to 1200 patients during 1700 infectious episodes (1-12 infectious episodes and thus antibiotic serum levels per patient).
Serum levels are not normally distributed. Do I have to do some sample modification prior to testing the differences regarding age and gender?
Even though there are multiple samples per patient, the second sample is from another infectious episode and has nothing to do with the first and so on.
So am I allowed to simply count each of the 1700 serum levels as separate?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convince us that you can: "the second sample has nothing to do with the first", therefore, you can. An experimental unit is a unit to which treatment is applied, as justified by the researcher/question of interest. As long as you convince the reviewers. But one might make a very compelling case that a person lucky enough to get 12 episodes has something going on compared to the one with 1 (which could be modeled as a covariate, for example), and if it is the same antibiotic family, a strong interaction with the number and time-to the prior episodes might be expected. Also, depending on the infection, there could be partial immunity (hence episode priority component).

Although not directly affecting your definition of an experimental unit, distributional assumptions are usually tested on a population basis, but you do not provide further information as to how you plan to address that, or what specific testing you are considering.